# Make an object reflect in correct angle

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, graphics

I am using vb.net for making a game. I have a ball (not actually, but supposedly) in the center of the screen. It moves towards another object, which has a circular surface and is supposed to reflect back in correct direction and angle.

Many games are based on the bouncing back of an object (most of them are based on advanced languages). But, I am not really able to make out how.

So, I tried to look at some things, like getting an angle from where it started by calculating the pixels from the initial point and sending it that many pixels in the opposite direction. A code which I tried for this is:

```
Dim x1, y1 as integer
x1 = object.left
y1 = object.top
```

This stores the object's co-ordinates at the starting, when it is in the center of the screen. While the following code tries to achieve what actually is required:

```
Dim a, b as integer
a = x1-object.left
b = x2-object.top
```

I have got the number of pixels it has moved, but I have no clue how to reflect back in the same angle using this, and whether this technique will even work or not.

So, basically what I want is:

[image]

Now, two situations arise:

- How to **reflect** object **from a plain surface**?
- How to **reflect** it **from circular surface**?

Comment: Your attempt is not precisely too elaborate (= you have done virtually nothing of what is required). This is a trigonometric (not too difficult, but neither completely straightforward) problem, which you can account for by thinking a bit about the potential alternatives and creating the algorithm by your own; or by relying on an external library already taking care of these situations. In any case, this is off-topic in SO: we don't build custom algorithms (solve mathematical problems) completely from scratch nor recommend external libraries.

Comment: I understand. But this is not exactly off-topic, right? There has to be solutions in the existing libraries as this seems to be a simple task. Whatever, your comment with the word 'trignometric' has shown me a new way. I'll be working on it any moment if I don't get a solution sooner. Thanks.

Comment: As said, this kind of situations are most likely being accounted for by quite a few libraries; but recommending a library is off-topic in SO. The word "trigonometric" sounds weird to you? How are you expecting to calculate angles then? (this is the part of maths taking care of angle calculations; sins, cosines, all this). In fact velocities have also to be accounted for and, thus technically speaking this is a physics/mechanics problem; although under the most likely conditions you might reduce the problem to simple distances (= lines) and consequently to pure trigonometry.

Comment: I didn't say 'weird'. It is just that I never thought I will get to use trigonometry in programming. And my comment meant that I now quite understand how I can go about it.

Comment: OK. But saying "never thought I will get to use trigonometry in programming" is more or less the same: your experience in creating algorithms involving maths/physics (e.g., anything involving movement; without relying on external libraries) is none. And thus building a solution by your own is not straightforward (= nothing that a bit of SO help might solve). I wouldn't ever recommend to face such an implementation (as said, neither too difficult nor too easy; but from an experienced enough programmer point of view) to someone with your experience. You should better learn basics.

Comment: And do you really think bragging about your experience is a good way to achieve success? I am not experienced, I admit. But considering my age, I have enough time and I will surely make my presence felt. Thank you for your knowledge. :)

Comment: Bragging? Saying you that you need X to accomplish Y is bragging? If you ask me "how can I go back in time" and I tell you "you cannot, under any circumstance; I can explain you the reasons". I would be bragging? (because of knowing something you don't know? But then why you ask at all?) Your age? How/why should I know your age and what has it to do with all this? To accomplish what you want you need certain knowledge; this is the reality. The fact of me or you having/not having this knowledge is irrelevant. Anyway... whatever you want: you are doing everything perfectly, continue like this.

Comment: Answering a question is surely not bragging. When did I say this? What you did above was. It is alright, now I wish to stop this thread.

Comment: You cannot lie about someone's behaviour and happily walk away. I have merely provided the required background to help you (and future readers) understand what is required to account for your problem. Such a reality has apparently offended you, what drove you to (personally) attack me. I have delivered exactly what was expected (objective help); you haven't (taking that help or leaving it, but not caring about the message bearer). I don't have to tolerate you lying about my behaviour; much less when I haven't said a word about yours (just gave an advice, which you are free to follow).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bouncing a ball off of another ball works exactly as bouncing it off a flat surface. As the balls only touch at one point, there is no difference to the moving ball if that point is part of a curved or a flat surface.

The ball acts just as if it was bouncing off of a flat plane, which is the tangent of the reflecting objects curve at that point (and also the tangent of the moving objects curve):

[image: Bounce]

The reflection movement is the angle mirrored around a line that is perpendicular to the plane, and goes through the center of the ball. (When the reflecting object is a ball, the line goes through the center of that too, which may help when you want to calculate it.)

Comment: This is not what the OP was looking for (pretty much a working solution); additionally, he does not seem to have the required mathematical background to create the whole algorithm (and thus to maximise this information). On the other hand, creating an algorithm properly accounting for the positions of all the balls bouncing without any limit (against walls and among them) is not trivial; and various sub-problems have to be taken care of. As a set of preliminary ideas, I guess that your answer is OK; but is very far away from being a comprehensive solution for this situation.

Comment: This didn't provide the actual answer. But yes, I have got fresh ideas with your answer. This would partially help me, I hope.

Comment: Finally, I found out the way. And this answer gave me 99% of what I needed. I was unable to get the co-ordinates or reflection, but after working out some of it, I finally got it. I have created a new library and the perpendicular from the point where the two circles meet actually gave the way.